# Rails Bootstrap Progress-bar Error: undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, progress-bar

Hi and thanks for reading!

Basically I've been trying to add a method which returns a percentage to my model such that I can use it for my view, in order to adjust the width of my progress-bar class.

My model method:

```
def percentage_funded
    result = (amount_funded / goal) * 100
    return result.to_s + '%'
end
```

If I try to return just one variable without doing the operation, it works. Otherwise I get an error saying:

```
undefined method `/' for nil:NilClass
```

My progress-bar:

```
<div class="bar" style="width: <%= project.percentage_funded %> ;"></div>
```

Any ideas why this could happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use nil in that operation.  You need to convert it to an integer or float with value of 0.

So try something like

```
result = (amount_funded.to_f / goal.to_f) * 100
```

(or to_i if you're using integers)

Comment: Thanks! It works now in the view but it breaks my controller when I try to use the same fields with the same error.